# AS3 search function to search 2d array coming from XML

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, search, 2d

So, I have this assignment where I have to load Xml file in flash then search through it  and display result when it is found.
So my xml looks like this:
    
    
     ju675
     kyu49

```
<item image="John.jpg" name="John" state = "New Jersey" >
<complex fid = "0"> mg749</complex>
<complex fid = "1"> ks749</complex>
<complex fid = "2"> ks678</complex>
    </item>

<item image="Smith.jpg" name="Smith" state = "California">
<complex fid = "0"> we649</complex>
<complex fid = "1"> sd449</complex>
<complex fid = "2"> df459</complex>
<complex fid = "3"> hj569</complex>
    </item>
</content>
```

I am having problem in tracing the complex. I want a search function that will search for state and complex both.So I upload XMl

```
loadXML();
function loadXML():void
{
var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeXMLHandler);

var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest('test4.xml');
try 
{
    loader.load(request);
} 
catch(error:Error) 
{
    trace('Impossible to load the document.');
}
}

 function completeXMLHandler(event:Event):void
 {
var loader:URLLoader=URLLoader(event.target);
var result:XML=new XML(loader.data);
var myXML:XMLDocument=new XMLDocument();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
myXML.parseXML(result.toXMLString());

for each (var usr in result.item)

var node:XMLNode=myXML.firstChild;
var items:int=int(node.childNodes.length);
for(var i:int=0;i<items;i++)
{

    var obj:Object=new Object();
    obj.name = node.childNodes[i].attributes.name;
    obj.state = node.childNodes[i].attributes.state;
    obj.image = node.childNodes[i].attributes.image;

    tyu.push(obj);

    var complexes:int=int(node.childNodes[i].childNodes.length);

    for(var j:int=0;j<complexes;j++)
    {

    var ghj:Object=new Object();
    ghj.complex=node.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
    comp.push(ghj);

    }
   main.push(comp);
   trace(main[0][1].complex)
}

currentUserbase = tyu.concat();
}
```

So if I try to trace "trace(main[1][1].complex)" it gives me an error.
Then I used search function:

```
function search(MouseEvent):void
{
currentUserbase = [];

for (var n:int = 0; n<tyu.length; n++){

if ((tyu[n].state.toLowerCase() == 
  search_state.text.toLowerCase() || search_state.text==""))
 {  
 currentUserbase.push(tyu[n]);
 }

 /*for (var k:int = 0; k<comp.length; k++){

if ((comp[n][k].complex.toLowerCase() ==
 autoComplete.text.toLowerCase() ||autoComplete.text==""))
{
    currentUserbase.push(comp[n][k]);
}
}*/



}
 updateList();
}
```

Guys I am trying to get it right from  days now. Please help me on this.Let me know if you want to see the .fla file.

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if you show us a sample search query and the results you expect. Either way, I would advice you to check the search functionality with E4X... as far as I can tell from what you wrote, it would be quite easy to do ;)

Comment: I have two input field on stage: autocomplete and search_state and when i press search btn, i want search function to go through xml file, say for example I put in autocomple: ks678 and state: New Jersey it will show me the Name, state and image of that particular node. I am using list component from flash to load all data from xml and when a input field is filled and search button is pressed it loads that particular node in the list and when we press that element in list it shows the name image and state. I am able to do that for state, but not for complex(autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

As @Cay suggests, have a look at E4X, it will save you some time, otherwise spent on converting to objects and traversing them.

Code could do with a bit of simplification:

```
loadXML();
function loadXML():void {
    var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader(new URLRequest('test4.xml'));//passing the url loads it automatically
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeXMLHandler);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorXMLHandler);
}
function errorXMLHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace('Impossible to load the document at url: ' + event.target.url);
}
function completeXMLHandler(event:Event):void {
    var result:XML=new XML(event.target.data);
    var items:XMLList = result.item;
    var complexes:XMLList = items.complex;
    var secondCompexItemsOnly:XMLList = items.complex.(@fid == "2");
    trace(items);
    trace(complexes);
    trace(secondCompexItemsOnly);
}
```

Have a look at this somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081111/how-do-i-display-xml-descendants-of-a-node-with-a-specific-attribute-in-as3/5081237#5081237).

Update:
@hanna, I've read through your comments carefully, but still I'm not 100% sure on what you want to achieve. I'm guessing you want to find the nodes with the right state(picked from the state input), and the right complex id(node value). I'm assuming you can have multiple item nodes with the right state, but with different names, that might contain complex nodes with the right complex node value.

Here's what I mean:

```
var myXML:XML = <content><item image="John.jpg" name="John" state = "New Jersey" >
<complex fid = "0"> mg749</complex>
<complex fid = "1"> ks749</complex>
<complex fid = "2"> ks678</complex>
    </item>

<item image="Smith.jpg" name="Smith" state = "California">
<complex fid = "0"> we649</complex>
<complex fid = "1"> sd449</complex>
<complex fid = "2"> df459</complex>
<complex fid = "3"> hj569</complex>
    </item>
</content>;

function getItemByStateAndID(state:String,id:String,source:XML):XML{
    var resultsByState:XMLList = source.item.(@state == state);
    if(resultsByState){//if there are states with the required name, look for complex nodes with requred id
        var result:XML = <content />;
        for each(var item:XML in resultsByState){//might be multiple items with the same state, but different content ?
            var resultById:XMLList = item.complex.(text() == id);
            if(resultById){//if there are complex nodes with the right id
                var resultItem:XML = item.copy();//copy the item node, so we preserve it's attributes(image,name,state)
                     resultItem.complex = resultById;//replace the complex node list with the result;
                result.appendChild(resultItem);//add it to our main result node, might be multiple item nodes with same states and different names, but the right id, b
            }   
        }
        return result;//got all item nodes with the right state and ids, return values;     
    }
    return null;//no results, return null   
}

trace(getItemByStateAndID("New Jersey","ks678",myXML));
/*outputs: <content>
<item image="John.jpg" name="John" state="New Jersey">
  <complex fid="2">ks678</complex>
</item>
</content>*/
```

HTH

Comment: Thanx for replying.

But my main problem is accesing these complex nodes through one variable, because in some nodes there will be 2 complex nodes in some there are 3, 4, 5 or even 7 so I wanted to know how can i access these. 

I was using E4X  
I used 

    for each (var usr in _data.item)
    { 

    allUserbase.push({name: usr.@name,state: usr.@state,image:usr.@image});

    }

but how this will help me in searching the complex node and displaying the data in that particular node attribute I am not sure.

Comment: @hanna I still don't think I fully understand what you need, but I feel I'm getting close.

Answer (score 0):

http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com/2011/01/search-through-xml-database-using-as3_12.html
I have something like this, but with only two search fields, say for ex in here the two search field are name and Job. Xml for this example is as following:

```
<userbase>
<user id="1" firstname="John" secondname="McCallister"
 sex="Male" age="26"   job="Driver" />
<user id="2" firstname="Adam" secondname="Jackson" sex="Male" 
age="25" job="Shop assistant" />
<user id="3" firstname="Mary" secondname="McCallister" sex="Female" 
age="24" job="Manager" />
</userbase>
```

So the upper one is working, but what i want is to work this example with the following XML.

```
userbase>
<user id="1" firstname="John" secondname="McCallister" sex="Male" age="29">
<job>driver</job>
<job>mechanic</job>
<job>guide</job>
</user>

<user id="2" firstname="Adam" secondname="Jackson" sex="Male" age="25">
<job>Teacher</job>
<job>Shop assistant</job>
</user>

<user id="3" firstname="Mary" secondname="McCallister" sex="Female" age="24">    
<job>Manager</job>
<job>doctor</job>
<job>shopkeeper</job>
<job>electrician</job>
</user>
</userbase>
```

Where I want to display first name and second name in the list. Create a search function for first name and job. When search is pressed it shows the first and second name to which the job is associate. As there are irregular number of job nodes i dont know how to execute it.

Comment: Hope this helps in helping me out..its been days i am banging my head with this..